# Android Studio - breakpoints not hit in Kotlin classes

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I started migrating my project from Java to Kotlin and I am facing a strange issue: breakpoints do not get hit in Kotlin classes, with the following error - no executable code found at line XX in class YY.

They work just fine in Java classes.

I am on Android Studio 3.5.2 (Stable Channel) and I am using Kotlin plugin 1.3.60. The OS is MacOS version 10.15.1.

I tried invalidate caches/restart with no success.

Comment: Please add some code/screenshot, maybe it will help.